# $-\frac{(-1)^n \left(\phi ^2+1\right)^2}{5 \phi ^2}=-e^{i \pi n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain *how*: $$-\frac{(-1)^n \left(\phi ^2+1\right)^2}{5 \phi ^2}=-e^{i \pi n}$$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not-so-subtle hint: $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\phi^2=\phi+1$, so that

> $$(\phi^2+1)^2 =(\phi+2)^2 =\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} +2\right)^2 =\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 =\left(\sqrt{5} \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 =5\phi^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$(-1)^n\equiv e^{i\pi n} \space \space \forall n \in \Bbb Z^+$$

Now prove that $$(\phi^2+1)^2=5\phi^2$$
via the identity $\phi^2=\phi+1$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $\phi^2=\phi+1$ and $e^{i \pi}=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to figure this out: you can also divide $n$ into even and odd cases. Write respectively $n=2k$ and $m=2l+1$ for some $k,l\in \mathbb{Z}$.

For even $n$, $\text{LHS}=-\frac{\left(\phi ^2+1\right)^2}{5 \phi ^2}$. Since $\phi$ is known, you can deduce $\text{LHS}=-1=\text{RHS}$ for this case (simple algebra). Same for odd $m$. It then follows that the equation holds for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.